# Dict of Dict to CSV with definded header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, export-to-csv

Following dict

```
result = {'Aktie': 'Bayer AG *', 'WKN': 'BAY001', 'Index': 'DAX', 'Branche': 'Chemie / Pharma / Gesundheit', 'RK': '3', 'Link': 'https://www.onvista.de/aktien/Bayer-Aktie-DE000BAY0017', 'Onvistaname': 'Bayer-Aktie-DE000BAY0017', 'Fundamentaldatenlink': 'https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/Bayer-Aktie-DE000BAY0017', '2019': {'Gewinn pro Aktie': ['  3,02  '], 'KGV': ['  24,06  '], 'Gewinnwachstum': ['  +73,88%  '], 'Dividende in Euro': ['  2,84  '], 'Dividende in Prozent': ['  2,84  ']}, '2020': {'Gewinn pro Aktie': ['  4,75  '], 'KGV': ['  15,31  '], 'Gewinnwachstum': ['  +43,13%  '], 'Dividende in Euro': ['  3,01  '], 'Dividende in Prozent': ['  3,01  ']}, '2021': {'Gewinn pro Aktie': ['  5,18  '], 'KGV': ['  14,04  '], 'Gewinnwachstum': ['  +23,21%  '], 'Dividende in Euro': ['  3,21  '], 'Dividende in Prozent': ['  3,21  ']}, '2022': {'Gewinn pro Aktie': ['  6,79  '], 'KGV': ['  10,71  '], 'Gewinnwachstum': ['  +27,24%  '], 'Dividende in Euro': ['  3,62  '], 'Dividende in Prozent': ['  3,62  ']}}
```

Should be exported to a csv.

This one was tried:

```
keys = result[0].keys()
with open('people.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(result)
```

The Result is a csv with the headers

```
Aktie,  WKN,    Index,  Branche,    RK, Link,   Onvistaname,    Fundamentaldatenlink,   2019,   2020,   2021,   2022
```

The dict should be exported as csv with the headers according to the key of the dict
For example:

```
Aktie,  WKN,    Index,  Branche,    RK, Link,   Onvistaname,    Fundamentaldatenlink, 2019 Gewinn pro Aktie, 2019 KGV [...], 2022 Dividende in Prozent
```

The first line then should be the values.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-dictionary/

The output row header should be the name of the key (for example 2022) and the nested key value (for example KGV)

> 2022 KGV
>
> 10,71

Comment: can you check `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)` looks good to me.

Comment: `result[0].keys()` produces a `KeyError`.

Comment: Result is a dict itself. So try using result.keys() to access the keys. And you can probably convert all your values into strings before writing them to csv

Comment: @Datanovice sorry i still get all value sets under the preceding nested key (example 2022). My bad i need to explain it better. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-dictionary/ i need the value set 2 exported under the row header with the name of keys and value set 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(result).to_csv("file.csv")
```

Note that json_normalize will be a "top-level" function in pandas starting with 1.0, so could just do pd.json_normalize when that comes out

Comment: Yes its the solution. Thank you really much!